# Workflow to run for multiple items in a sharepoint list daily

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I currently have a list which has a lot of savings information for finance to validate. I have created an overdue flag, so that if something has not been validated for more than 7 days, it should mark as "Overdue". I would also like to create a workflow to send finance an email daily on all the items marked "Overdue". Is this possible?

EDIT: Including my currently site workflow below. It is looping through the items, but it is not sending a List of "Overdue" items and only sending an email with the last reference ID in the list thats overdue. What I would like the Email to read it:

Please Validate the below:
Ref ID -overdue by # days
....
Ref ID - overdue by # days
[image: My current workflow]

Answer (score 1):

You can put a pause for duration action with a loop to accomplish this.  Included a screen shot below of something similar I've done.  Use a 1 day pause if that's what you need.  You want to avoid looping without a pause since there's not a need to have the workflow looping constantly.

[image]

Comment: Nate - I created a site workflow, and I see that it keeps looping through the items. What I want the workflow to do is compile this list into an email and send it tot he validators. What am I doing wrong? Currently, it is only sending the last line in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Create a site workflow and add pause action into it

Comment: would you be able to give me more information on this? What do I need to do? I tried to follow instructions from another walkthrough - but nothing really happened, so I know I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Pauses are a terrible idea.  Just because the workflow is paused does not mean it is still not running in the backgroud.  You can overload your timerjobs and your farm will pay a hefty performance price for it.  They can also timeout leaving abandon workflows in the queue that are also still running.

If you want to run a workflow on lists everyday at the same time, you could:

```
1. create a timerjob to run your action (best practice option if on premise)
2. use pauses and breaks (terrible idea, and not best practice)
3. use Infomration Management Policy on your list (probably your best option)
```

[Information Management Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/information-management-policy-planning) will allow you to run your workflow at a set time everyday, or when you choose.  There are several other uses for this OOTB solution which is available on all lists.  Please read the attached article and stay away from pause events in your SPD workflows.  You can set your overdue logic and have it run everyday on all of the list items at once.  This should be your solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. Any idea how I could get it to do what I need it to do however? That still doesnt seem to be working =(

Comment: Yo will not have to loop through all of your items anymore.  Have a single logic true to say if x != y than send the email.  Have flags in there to restart your logic.  The IMP will run on each list item for you. no need to loop anymore.  Your current logic will not work anymore, but the logic to replace it should be quite simple.  Your WF will run everyday and the same time.  Create logic to support that instead of a loop through all of your items.

Comment: hi Dev, I looked at the IMP, but I dont think that is what I am looking for. My loop program (screenshot above) isnt working first :( I just want to see what I am doing wrong.